# Need help on converting Ruby function to Python function

Tags: python, ruby, python-3.x, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to create a Python function to convert the lists (Objects of arrays in ELK term) to dictionary. I found a sample Ruby function which does that and I'm trying to convert it to Python function for my usage. I'm finding hard time to get the output. The output will be inserted back to Elastic Search.

- Ruby Function - I found in Internet

  ```
  def arrays_to_hash(h)
            h.each do |k,v|
              # If v is nil, an array is being iterated and the value is k.
              # If v is not nil, a hash is being iterated and the value is v.
              value = v || k
              if value.is_a?(Array)
                  # "value" is replaced with "value_hash" later.
                  value_hash = {}
                  value.each_with_index do |v, i|
                      value_hash[i.to_s] = v
                  end
                  h[k] = value_hash
              end

              if value.is_a?(Hash) || value.is_a?(Array)
                arrays_to_hash(value)
              end
            end
          end
  ```
- Python Function - I'm trying - Upon seeing the O/P i can see the first list inside the dictionary is getting converted but the nested list inside that is still present

  `def array_path(my_dict):
  for k,v in my_dict.items():
      if isinstance(v,list):
          print (len(v))
          for i, item in enumerate(v):
              my_dict2[str(i)] = item
          my_dict[k] = my_dict2
      elif isinstance(v,dict):
          array_path(v)
      else:
          my_dict[k] = v`

**Input**

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "test": {
    "steps": [
      {
        "response_time": "100"
      },
      {
        "response_time": "101",
        "more_nested": [
          {
            "hello": "world"
          },
          {
            "hello2": "world2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**

**Expected Output**

**

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "test": {
    "steps": {
      "0": {
        "response_time": "100"
      },
      "1": {
        "response_time": "101",
        "more_nested": {
          "0": {
            "hello": "world"
          },
          "1": {
            "hello2": "world2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Current O/P

```
{'0': {'response_time': '100'},
 '1': {'more_nested': [{'hello': 'world'}, {'hello2': 'world2'}],
  'response_time': '101'}}
```

Comment: Please give some sample inputs and outputs. It's very unclear what behaviour you actually expect of this method.

Comment: @TomLord Thanks for your response. Provided the input and O/P

Comment: the line `my_dict[k] = my_dict2` should not be in the for loop (in ruby it comes after `end`)

Comment: @bobrobbob, Thanks. I changed the indent. Still the O/P is same. The nested list inside is printed as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the original script stopped its check to list, not implementing a solution for a list of dicts. looks ok now

```
def array_path(my_dict):
    if type(my_dict) is dict:
        for k, v in my_dict.items():
            my_dict[k] = array_path(v)
    elif type(my_dict) is list:
        return {str(i): array_path(item) for i, item in enumerate(my_dict)}
    return my_dict
```

Comment: Thanks, Working as Expected